# desktop application in libgdx giving error after configuration

Tags: android, libgdx

I forgot to note the first line on [libgdx wiki](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup)
   and using java 1.7 now for libgdx..

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
 public class DesktopGame {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
            new LwjglApplication(new Game(), "Game", 480, 320, false);
    }
  }
```

this is the only file which is giving me error to `Configure build path`
even after completing all configuration steps.

Is there any other way to tackle it?

In the case, if I installed java 6, will it affect the project conf and working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Java 1.7 too, and Iam sure that may not be the issue. I would recommend you to use the gdx-setup-ui, for your project creation. Check here http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetupNew , its much easier to create projects using this setup.

Comment: have you tried samples of libgdx https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/demos

Comment: After using that ui, superjumper and pax-britanic giving error "The hierarchy of type SuperjumperGwt is inconsistent" at line " public class SuperJumperGwt extends GwtApplication {
 "